# Splitting up project with react & webpack4; html tags are unexpected tokens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

### **Background**

I'm using react, babel, webpack4, and es6(or maybe es7)

I have some modules that are reused by multiple react projects. For this reason I've created a 'Standard' folder that contains these modules so that they are kept separate from any specific project.

### **Problem**

In my react project I edited my webpack.config.js to contain

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.css', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      Standard: '/Path/To/Standard',
    }
  }
```

Then to import a module from it I call

```
import MyModule from 'Standard/MyModule.js'
```

When I do this, it looks like the html tags aren't recognized within the files in my Standard folder

### **Error Messages**

For `webpack-dev-server --inline`

```
ERROR in /Path/To/Standard/MyModule.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Path/To/Standard/MyModule.js: Unexpected token (13:8)

  11 | var MyModule = (props) => {
  12 |     return (
> 13 |         <header id='Header' className={props.className}>
```

For `webpack`

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! default@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the default@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

---

### **Debugging attempts**

I've tried to create a webpack.config.js and package.json inside my standard folder(in addition to my project folder), but nothing really seems to help

I tried some npm installs to install babel, because that seemed like the most obvious solution, [and is used on this answer in an older webpack version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905227/reactjs-unexpected-token-error), but I still get the same problems

```
  npm install --save react
  npm install --save babel @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
  npm install --save babel-core babel-loader babel-cli babel-preset-env babel-preset-react webpack
```

Also it looks like [this post](https://medium.com/@frewin.christopher/update-for-2018-for-anyone-else-running-into-errors-that-webpack-was-complaining-about-the-jsx-18dd5447bcd1) which is a reply to [this blog](https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/how-to-create-a-react-component-and-publish-it-in-npm-668ad7d363ce) might be related, but this solution didn't work for me.

---

### **package.json**

```js
{
    "scripts": {
        "webpack": "webpack",
        "start": "http-server"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.8.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.5.1",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "webpack": "^4.28.0"
    }
}
```

### **webpack.config.js**

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');

const config = {
    mode: 'development',     // set mode option, 'development' or 'production'
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.m?js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.css', '.js', '.jsx'],
    }
}

module.exports = config;
```

### **.babelrc**

```js
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of MyModule.js? My guess is you need to wrap what you're returning with either a fragment <> or any containing element.

Answer (score 0):

You're 1st problem here is that babel is not parsing code from you're packages (error say  that it try to exec not transpiled jsx code).

Maybe the babel presets is not accessible in you're package directory.
You can try copying them or set them directly in the webpack config

```
                    {
                        loader : 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets       : [
                                ['@babel/preset-env',
                                    {// here the presets params
                                    }],
                                '@babel/preset-react'
                            ],
                            plugins       : [
                                ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {
                                    "loose": true
                                }]
                            ]
                        }
                    },
```

Possibly the exclude regexp of babel exclude the packages from where you want importing scripts :

```
     exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
```

So you can use a custom function like that :

```
     exclude: {test:(pathName)=>(isInternalCode(pathName))),
```

Or use negative lookahead in the reg exp like :

/(node_modules(?!\b(?:OneFolder|AnotherIncluded))|bower_modules)/

That's said the usual way is to compile independently you're packages ( by externalizing all theirs deps from the builds & adding them to "peerDependencies" or "dependencies" )

Also; there a plugin to make "inheritable" packages; [layer-pack](https://github.com/n8tz/layer-pack).

It allow making "inheritable" projects, & deal with node_modules & webpack to make inheritable "code layers" & even work when compiling node scripts or using monorepo structure

Using it you can simply put you're components in a shared inheritable package

it come with some nice features like glob resolving, which help including an unknown number of files.

There is samples [here](https://github.com/n8tz/layer-pack-samples) & doc [here](https://github.com/n8tz/layer-pack/blob/master/DOC.MD)

Hope it help :)